# C# No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox to a known managed provider native type

Tags: c#

Please Help!I got this err once i viewed in browser !! :

No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox to a known managed provider native type.

--- Not Able to execute --

=========================================

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[1].ToString();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "ManageMember";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@check", "a");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", UserNameTxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", PasswordTxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", FullNameTxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", EmailTxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", PhoneTxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", CompanyTxt);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", RdList.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthDate", BirthdateTxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@question", Quastxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@answer", AnswTxt.Text);

conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
lblMsg.Text = "User Added Successfully";
conn.Close();
```

Comment: In the future, always post the exception stack trace or at least indicate which line of code is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", CompanyTxt);
```

To

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", CompanyTxt.Text);
```

Then smack yourself in the forehead.